# Error while lifting the server

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, sequelize.js

I tried to make a project using `sails.js, ORM sequelize and postgreSQL`. While lifting the server, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

[image]

I made sure that all the parameters and connections are correct but I'm unable to figure out the reason of this error. Please suggest a solution if possible.

Comment: For future reference, copying and pasting the text is much more useful than screenshots. It's also searchable.

Comment: alright, will follow that in future..thanx.

Comment: The database server is actively refusing the connection, so there must be something wrong with your setup. Perhaps try connecting directly with sequelize, or directly using the mysql connector

Comment: check if you've mysql server running properly or try reinstalling mysql

Comment: or may be you can try running project with silly or verbose and see where the hook is holding, try lifting sailsjs project like `sails lift --verbose` OR `sails lift --silly`